# Magento enterprises edition

Tags: magento, dns, subdomain, licensing

Does magento enterprises edition support multiple domains and server?
In short how server and domains can be managed through Enterprises edition?
Under one license can we have multiple domains for a single website?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution in their own license.
http://magento.com/legal/terms/enterprise

But using its core functionality to setup multiple stores can be possible